# Am having random problem when creating a table in apex orcale

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Am having this problem making the table

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE Request_NA(
Request_ID Number(8) Primary Key Not Null,
Student_ID Number(8) Not NUll,
Staff_ID Number(8) Not Null,
Temporary_Withdrawal Char(3) Not Null,
Permanet_Withdrawal Char(3) Not Null,
Request_Date Date Not Null,
Data_Form Varchar(15) Not Null,
Necessary_Interventions Char(3) Not Null,
Rentention_Form Varchar(15) Not Null,
Student_Extension Char(3) Not Null,
CourseLead_Signature Varchar(10) Not Null,
Meeting_Attended Char(3) Not Null,
Student_Signature Varchar(10) Not Null,
Last_Date_Attendance Date Not Null,
Return_Date Date Not Null,
FOREIGN KEY (Student_ID) REFERENCES Students_NA(Student_ID)
FOREIGN KEY (Staff_ID) REFERENCES Staff_NA(Staff_ID)
);
```

Comment: Please put code and errors in your question as text not as images.  It appears that you are missing a comma at the end of line 16.

Comment: And you're missing a comma at the end of line 17.

Comment: I did put the commas for line 16, 17 and 18 it says ORA-00904: : invalid identifier now

Comment: Nobody said to add one to line 18... just 16 and 17.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone the commas for line 16 and 17 was right it worked

Answer (score 1):

There's a comma missing at the line of lines #16 and #17:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Request_NA(
  2  Request_ID Number(8) Primary Key Not Null,
  3  Student_ID Number(8) Not NUll,
  4  Staff_ID Number(8) Not Null,
  5  Temporary_Withdrawal Char(3) Not Null,
  6  Permanet_Withdrawal Char(3) Not Null,
  7  Request_Date Date Not Null,
  8  Data_Form Varchar(15) Not Null,
  9  Necessary_Interventions Char(3) Not Null,
 10  Rentention_Form Varchar(15) Not Null,
 11  Student_Extension Char(3) Not Null,
 12  CourseLead_Signature Varchar(10) Not Null,
 13  Meeting_Attended Char(3) Not Null,
 14  Student_Signature Varchar(10) Not Null,
 15  Last_Date_Attendance Date Not Null,
 16  Return_Date Date Not Null,
 17  FOREIGN KEY (Student_ID) REFERENCES Students_NA(Student_ID),
 18  FOREIGN KEY (Staff_ID) REFERENCES Staff_NA(Staff_ID)
 19  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

Also, Oracle recommends us to use `VARCHAR2` datatype, not `VARCHAR`.

---

BTW, you'd rather copy/paste code itself, not an image. We can't *execute* an image, but could do so with code.

Comment: Hi thank you I added the comma but the error still happening

Comment: The same goes with line #17. See code which *works*.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for help i was stressing so much how to fix much hope you all have great day thank you again!